# What is the etymology of "gatefold"?

Tags: meaning, etymology

What does the word "gatefold" mean?

Sure, I know what it *is* (the whole internet is very eager to tell me what it is), but where does it come from?

The "gate" part that is, I can guess the "fold" part. But I can't find any sense of the word "gate" that would pertain to a way of folding paper.

Comment: Hint: gates have hinges.

Comment: Hm, you mean it refers to the doors in the gate, rather than the gateway itself? Interesting. Off to do more research...

Comment: From [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gatefold): *foldout; especially :  one with a single fold that opens out like a gate*

Comment: Still, a gatefold is usually folded like a regular book (i.e., the bit that folds is in the middle and the bits that move are on the sides), not like a normal gate (the bits that fold are on the sides and the bits that move are in the middle). So why name it after a gate? Seems rather unintuitive.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet- But if you hold it like a book and want to open it, it opens just the way a single gate would open to reveal the novel (or the garden) therein.

Comment: @Jim I suppose that’s true. Still seems an odd thing to name it for, since the two standard kinds of gate unfold in fundamentally different ways. [This page](http://www.saxoprint.co.uk/blog/gate-fold-leaflets/) says that a gatefold is one that opens like a double gate (or window), rather than like a single gate or a book. In fact, most printing sites I can find agree with that—which is different from Wikipedia’s and the dictionaries’ definitions (and my own mental image). I am now officially confused.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Darn it, I need to actually follow your links before I write answers! I honestly found it independently, so if you would like credit for an answer, if you post one I’ll delete mine. The Wikipedia article seems to be talking about a sleeve insert like one might find in a record jacket or a CD case, not an actual foldout page like you find in *National Geographic*.

Comment: @tchrist It was the first hit on Google, so it’s hardly surprising you found it too. :-) (The sleeve insert usage is the only one I’ve really ever heard before—for the type mentioned by Saxo Print, I’ve always used _window fold_.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It seems that the record people are using the term quite differently from how bookbinders use the term.

Comment: We need more questions like this if etymology is ever going to attract enough male students.

Comment: @JohnLawler: Enough...to procreate with the existing female students of etymology, in order to create more little etymologists? Who will watch to establish their origins?

Comment: Etymologists are normally exogamic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In [her blog on Design Context, Sophie Wilson](http://s-wilson1013-dc.blogspot.com/2011/11/what-is-design-for-printtypes-of-fold.html) details the various types of folds and provides the following useful illustration:

[image: Sophie Wilson's fold illustration]

Regular people call pretty much all of those *foldouts*, but bookmakers use *gatefold* as a particular term of the trade. The simple reason that it’s called a *gatefold* is because it folds out like a double-gate — that is, one with two separate “doors” where one opens to the left and the other to the right.

[This article on “What you need to know about gate fold leaflets”
by Saxoprint in the UK](http://www.saxoprint.co.uk/blog/gate-fold-leaflets/) explains the origin of the term in this way:

> ### Name and background
>
> Like so many other kinds of fold, the gate fold is based on a parallel fold – i.e. where the folded edges run exactly parallel to one another and the outer sides are folder in one direction.
>
> As for the name, **if you guessed that the “gate fold” (sometimes written “gatefold”) is called so because it opens a bit like a double gate, you’d be right.** It’s also called the “window fold” for a similar reason: i.e. it is divided down the centre into two flaps which are “hinged” on the folds and can be opened out – much like an old religious triptych. On a six-sided folder, the two flaps fold over a flat, square side, but this square can also be folded down the middle to make an eight-sided, closed format.

That page has many diagrams and examples of various kinds of foldouts.

Apparently, the record industry took to calling simple folds gatefolds, even though they were not such.  In [this article on how to fold a brochure from PrePressure](http://www.prepressure.com/finishing/how-to-fold-a-brochure), they draw a distinction:

> ### Half fold or single fold
>
> As the name implies, simply fold the page in half. **Sometimes this is also called a gatefold**, for example in the music industry where vinyl LP albums were often packaged in a gatefold cover.
>
> ### Gate fold or window fold
>
> With a gatefold the two outside panels 1 and 3 each fold towards the middle. They are slightly smaller than half of the sheet.

So it appears that the record people call just about anything folded a gatefold, but this is not how the term is used by bookbinders.  For example, the [Wikipedia article on Allman Brothers Band’s *Eat a Peach* album](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eat_a_Peach) calls this image from the article “gatefold art”:

[image: Eat a Peach album cover]

Notice there is just a single fold.

Comment: I don't get it..  What does "foldouts" have to do with placing bets?

Comment: +1 for the PrePress quote that specifically implies that the record industry usage is secondary, despite the fact that it's probably the most common and familiar use of the word.